# Ada Syntax for initializing dynamically allocated array

Tags: ada, gnat

What is the correct syntax for initializing a dynamically allocated array in Ada? I have tried this:

```
type Short_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Short;
Items : access Short_Array;
Items := new Short_Array(1..UpperBound)'(others => 0);
```

which results in a compiler error - "binary operator expected". And this:

```
type Short_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Short;
Items : access Short_Array;
Items := new Short_Array(1..UpperBound);
Items.all := (others => 0);
```

which seems to raise a SEGFAULT surprisingly. Not sure what's going on there but wanted to get the syntax right before I start chasing my tail.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating an array?

Comment: Your second version works fine here, macOS, GNAT GPL 2015/2016. What OS/compiler are you using?

Comment: @JimRogers It is part of a record type that I do not know the size of at compile time.

Comment: @SimonWright Yeah, I just tried it in a separate test file vs. as part of my larger program and it worked fine. Not sure what the deal was. GNATMAKE GPL 2016 (20160515-49) distributed with GPS GPL from AdaCore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Ada2012 you can do the following:

```
type Short_Array is array(Natural range <>) of Short with
   Default_Component_Value => 0;
Items : access Short_Array := new Short_Array(1..UpperBound);
```

The use of default initial values for arrays is explained in section 2.6 of the Ada 2012 Rationale http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-2-6.html

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a stack-based approach or a "malloc()" approach?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach in Ada is to define the record as a discriminant record, with the discriminant determining the size of the array field.

```ada
type Items_Record (Size : Natural) is record
   -- Some non-array fields of your record
   Items : Short_Array(1..Size);
end record;
```

An instance of the record can then be allocated in an inner block

```ada
Get(Items_Size);
declare
   My_Record : Items_Record(Size => Items_Size);
begin
   -- Process the instance of Items_Record
end;
```

The record is dynamically allocated on the stack. If the record size is very large you will encounter a stack overflow issue. If not, this works very well. One advantage of this approach is the instance is automatically de-allocated when the end of the block is reached.

Answer (score 1):

The `SEGFAULT` in your second example comes most certainly from the initialization.

Compare

```ada
type Short_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Short;
Items : access Short_Array;
Items := new Short_Array(1..UpperBound);
Items.all := (others => 0);
```

And this:

```ada
type Short_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Short;
Items : access Short_Array;
Items := new Short_Array(1..UpperBound);
for I in 1..UpperBound loop
   Items(I) := 0;
end loop;
```

And play with different values of `ulimit -Ss` which sets the allowed size of the stack.

The point is that

```ada
Items.all := (others => 0);
```

allocates an array on the stack and copy it in your heap-allocated array. So you think you are working on the heap but still needs a lot of stack. If your array is too big for your `ulimit -Ss` (or considering both soft and hard limits `ulimit -s`), you will segfault (or get a `STORAGE_ERROR`) though you think you are all on the heap.

To mitigate this problem, (though it might not work in every situation, *eg* if `UpperBound` is dynamic…), you can compile your code either with:

- `"-fstack-usage"` (to get usage information for each unit)
- `"-Wstack-usage=2000"` (or any limit more accurate to your case, see [gnat's documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html#static-stack-usage-analysis) for more infos) to yield warnings for functions using too much stack (or having unbounded stack usage).

The second option could have issued a warning and pointed you to your stack overflow.

Comment: BTW, if anyone knows of a static analysis tool that could detect this error, I'm eager to hear! AFAICT neither gnatcheck nor codepeer (level 4) could detect this.